# Java SQL quotes in query strings

Tags: java, sql, keyword, quotes

I have the following code to executing a sql query:

```
query = String.format("select * from users where user_name = '%s';", results.getString(1));
results2 = mStmt.executeQuery(query);
```

One user_name in the dataset has value "O'brien". This ruins my query due to the single parenthesis in "O'brien. The query would become:

```
select * from users where user_name = 'O'brien'
```

What is the strategy to overcome this and not modify the data?

**EDIT**: The prepared statement does fix the single quote problem however that was only part of the problem. One of the string values I have contains the word "UNDER". which is a SQL keyword. For example I have a preparedStatement called insertAll with the query:

```
insert into names (id, val1, val2, val3, val4, tTime, val5) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Could explain what you mean?

Comment: Use a [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) with query parameters

Comment: From the way it looks, your query for the prepared statement should be  "insert into names (id, val, val1, val2, val3, val4, tTime, val5) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", check that there is a **?** symbol for every parameter you're about to add in the statement.

Comment: Yes, and that's not a problem in your query. The problem is that you're not defining the parameters that you really need in your query. By the way, you have 8 columns and you're only setting 7 values (and that's a SQL syntax error).

Comment: I fixed that and I still have the same problem... Sorry for being troublesome...

Comment: It looks like in the end the advices worked for you :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set your parameters with prepareStatement.  Your code is a SQL injection exploitable code from the book. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: I am now using a prepared Statement and it still fails with a whitespace character?

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus update your code to check for new problems in it.

Comment: Did you see my edit? I discovered my other problem was a SQL keyword

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus I can see your edit, but I don't see your actual code to analyze the new problems.

Comment: Trim the string before adding it

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus please post your current code and the StackTrace to see the error. In its actual state, it looks that there is no error. Help us to help you.

Comment: @CodeKingPlusPlus please, **please** post your current code: `String sql = "insert into names (name) values (?)"; PreparedStatement pstms = con.prepareStatement(sql); //more code...`. Until now, you haven't post anything that any person could examine to help you with your problem. If you continue like this, the question won't be answered and could even be closed.

Comment: Sorry, I was just editing more. I think I have all of it now.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) instead, avoid the tedious and error-prone issue of escaping quotes in sql queries altogether?

The could would look something like this (sorry, I didn't actually run this, but you should get the idea):

```
query = "select * from users where user_name = ?";
PreparedStatement p = new PreparedStatement(con, query);
p.setString(1, results.getString(1));
results2 = p.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Prepared statements fix one of my problems, now I have a bizarre issue with whitespace?

Comment: An issue with whitespace where?  In the query, in the names in the database, in the output?  Sounds like a different question altogether.

Comment: Actually I figured it out. It does not like Keywords such as UNDER. How would I fix this?